# Reference error on node.js while include file

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm new to `node.js`. i have two files. they are `index.js` and `db.js`

my `index.js` is

```
var connection = require('./db.js');

device = new Device({
    id: 93,
    name: 'test1'
});

device.save();
```

my `db.js` is

```
var mysql      = require('mysql2');
var mysqlModel = require('mysql-model');

var appModel = mysqlModel.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : 'root',
  database : 'db',
}); 

var Device = appModel.extend({
    tableName: "DeviceTable",
});
```

here i'm getting the `error` while running **node index.js**

> device = new Device({
>
> ```
>             ^
> ```
>
> ReferenceError: Device is not defined.

but while inserting the following into `db.js` itself. It worked fine. it does the `insert`.

```
var mysql      = require('mysql2');
var mysqlModel = require('mysql-model');

var appModel = mysqlModel.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : 'root',
  database : 'db',
}); 

var Device = appModel.extend({
    tableName: "DeviceTable",
});

var device = new Device({
    id: 93,
    name: 'test1'
});

device.save();
```

why i'm getting the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want something from the db module to be accessible in other modules, you need to expose it, by using `module.exports`

add to the end of your `db.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  appModel : appModel,
  Device : Device
};
```

and then in your `index.js` you can do:

```
device = new connection.Device({
  id: 93,
  name: 'test1'
});
```

you can read more about it [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/)

Answer (score 2):

node.js treats every file as a module. so to include any source file into another you need to export it at the source end and import it using require at the importing file.